# Why i can't drop the 'checkSelfPermission' on my code ?

Tags: android

I wrote simple code that return the gpsLocation of the device. 
When i compile it i get an error about that i did not used the 'checkSelfPermission' of access the GPS and Network.

When i get to the 'checkSelfPermission' code i get an exception.

1. how can i avoid the 'must' use of the checkSelfPermission method ?
2. why i get the exception ?

   ```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
     private void getLocation() {
       try {
             locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

       // getting GPS status
       isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

       // getting network status
       isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

       if (isNetworkEnabled)
       {
           **// the exception is on the 'checkSelfPermission'** 
               if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   return;
               }

           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                   MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                   MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                   this);

           if (locationManager != null)
           {

               location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
               if (location != null) {
                   latitude = location.getLatitude();
                   longitude = location.getLongitude();
               }
           }
       }

       if (isGPSEnabled)
       {
           if (location == null)
           {
               locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                       MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                       MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                       this);

               if (locationManager != null)
               {
                   location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                   if (location != null)
                   {
                       latitude = location.getLatitude();
                       longitude = location.getLongitude();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from the android documentation :

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
> apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.
>
> System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and
> dangerous:
>
> 1.Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your
> app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the
> permission automatically.
>
> 2.Dangerous permissions can give the app
> access to the user's confidential data.

If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires that permission. And accessing the device location needs a dangerous permission so you have to check and request for Location permission at runtime.

To check that your app has been granted permission, you can use:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

If the app has the permission, the method returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`, and the app can proceed with the operation. If the app does not have the permission, the method returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`, and the app has to explicitly ask the user for permission.

So you cannot avoid `checkSelfPermission`.

Comment: I cann't use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission in eclipse.can you tell me how can i use runtime permition in eclipse using your solution.

Comment: Using eclipse changes nothing, the way to ask permissions during runtime remains same.

Comment: in eclipse ,runtim permition code will not work.I am using v4 library.can you provide me latest support library